# Input from the list for python

Tags: python, arrays, list, input

Assuming that I already have a list of names, I want to print "wrong" if a user's input of a name does not match one already in the list.

My code:

```
name = ['ali', 'abu', 'amir']
print name

new = raw_input( "enter name")
if new == name:
    print "correct"
else:
    print "wrong"
```

When I input the name 'amir' it will print out "wrong", despite the fact that it is in my list.

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace `if new == name:` with:

```
if new in name:
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than equate the new name to the list, you need to check if it is *in* the list.

```
print 'correct' if new in name else 'wrong'
```

Answer (score 0):

To check that an element is in the list, you can **use the `in` operator.**

```
name = ['ali', 'abu', 'amir']
print name

new = raw_input( "enter name ")
if new in name: # check 'new' is in the list 'name'
    print "correct"
else:
    print "wrong"
```

**What you were doing wrong?**

When you were doing `new==name`, you were actually comparing the input `new` with the list `name` which is `False` thereby printing `wrong` everytime.

```
In [1]: name = ['ali', 'abu', 'amir']

In [2]: new = raw_input( "enter name ")
enter name abcd

In [3]: new in name
Out[3]: False 'abcd' is not in the list 'name'

In [4]: new = raw_input( "enter name ")
enter name ali

In [5]: new in name
Out[5]: True # 'ali' is in the list 'name'

In [6]: new==name
Out[6]: False # Because comparing 'ali' with list 'name'
```